# Delphi: positioning a form in a dll

Tags: forms, delphi, dll

I am creating a form in a dll. No packages. The form in the dll is called by using the exported procedure:

```
procedure ShowAbout(const AppHandle: THandle); stdcall;
  var
    aHandle: THandle;
    form:  TfrmAbout;  / my form in some other unit in the dll
  begin

    aHandle:= Application.Handle;
    Application.Handle:= AppHandle;

    form :=TfrmAbout.Create(Application);
    form.ShowModal;
    form.Free;
    Application.Handle:= aHandle;
  end;
```

The form displays well and there are no problems. Now, the only thing I would like it to do is to behave positioning as poMainFormCenter (I want it to display always over the main form (the form that is calling the dll).

I have tried using form :=TfrmAbout.Create(Application.MainForm); etc but no luck.

Any tricks which would help here?

Comment: You should pass `Application` pointer instead of just window handle. It is crude, but unfortunately does not work other way

Comment: Absolutely do not pass `Application` pointer. You can't pass objects from one instance of the VCL to another. You need to be using runtime packages for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VCL `Position` mechanism relies on the other forms in the application all running with the  same version of the VCL. This is clearly not the case here and you will have to position the form manually.

Find out the position of the main form by calling [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing the main form handle. Then you need to work out where your form needs to go to be in the center of that form.

```
procedure PositionForm(Form: TForm; MainWindow: HWND);
var
  MainBounds: TRect;
  MainWidth, MainHeight: Integer;
begin
  if GetWindowRect(MainWindow, MainBounds) then
  begin
    MainWidth := MainBounds.Right-MainBounds.Left;
    MainHeight := MainBounds.Bottom-MainBounds.Top;
    Form.Left := MainBounds.Left + (MainWidth - Form.Width) div 2;
    Form.Top := MainBounds.Top + (MainHeight - Form.Height) div 2
  end;
```

By the way, the handle you are passing is an `HWND` rather than a `THandle`. You should change you code accordingly. It won't change behaviour, but it is logically correct to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't use pacakges, your EXE and your DLL both have a seperate TApplication instance. TApplication.MainForm in your EXE is not seen in your DLL. Changeing TApplication.Handle does not make the MainForm change. Find other ways to position the form right, but better yet: Use packages, you will run into more problems if you don't.

Comment: There are times when you need to use DLLs. For example an Office add-in. That said, packages are certainly cleaner if they fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting form.ParentWindow to the handle of the parent window? You should pass it as a param to ShowAbout, or you *could* dig it up from Application object (something like Application.ActiveForm) but I'm not sure it would work.

Calling `TfrmAbout.Create(Application.MainForm)` just specifies that Application.MainForm is responsible for destruction of the form, it should have nothing to do with window hierarchy, also I'm not sure you should be using auto destruction if you create form in a separate dll.

Comment: Yes, tried that. Unfortunately, if I add form.ParentWindow := parentHandle (passed as a parameter), the form hangs and doesn't show.

Comment: That's strange, it should work. Could you update your question to show *when* do you set ParentWindow property. Also, what is `aHandle` for in your code? You shoud have only one app handle.

Comment: ParentWindow is what you use to show one form as a child of another. It sounds like this question is about top-level windows.

Comment: Yes, ParentWindow seems to be about something else. BTW aHandle is stores the Application handle from the Forms unit used in the dll just before assigning the handle from the calling application, just to restore it back when the dll is about to bee closed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, but if MainForm is parent window of a form, then that form *will* be top-level when shown modal, no? Also, a welcome side effect is that when MainForm is activated it will auto activate modal form, i.e. modal form that has focus and has captured app msg loop won't be hidden by the mainform. Also, it should make CenterParent work, as OP requested

Comment: No, when you set a ParentWindow, the child is no longer top level. Are you thinking of the windows owner? MS do confuse the terms by overloading them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm thinking of `SetWindowLong(win32window, GWL_HWNDPARENT, formhandle);`

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing as what I'm talking about. MSDN says this: "You must not call SetWindowLong with the GWL_HWNDPARENT index to change the parent of a child window. Instead, use the SetParent function."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you, didn't know that. It's just that owners/parents have different meanings with regards to whether it's a control or a form, or whether it's VCL or WinAPI terminology. :)

Comment: @Boris Yes there is huge scope for confusion with the terminology